# No home directory, logging in with HOME=/

Tags: linux, useradd

Created a new user in Ubuntu 11.04 using:

```
$ useradd -d /home/dummy -m dummy
```

Now, after this I set its password using `passwd dummy`, but when I login to that user using `su - dummy`. I get the message:

> No home directory, logging in with HOME=/

If I check the user account dummy's entry in `/etc/passwd`:

```
 $ cat /etc/passwd | grep dummy
dummy:x:1001:1001::/home/dummy:/bin/bash**
```

I manually created the directory to resolve this issue through `mkdir /home/dummy`.

Now, the error seems to be resolved, but I'm amazed as to why no files like `bash_profile` are created in that home directory.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Do you have anything in /etc/skel?

Comment: @manatwork having anything in /etc/skel wont matter if he created the directory with `mkdir`. /etc/skel is only used when something like `useradd` creates it.

Comment: What is the output of useradd -D

Comment: `-m` means the home directory should have been created and populated from `/etc/skel`. What happens if you create another user? Check what `useradd` is doing. Are you seeing any message? If you can't find anything, post the output of `strace useradd -d /home/test1 -m test1`.

Answer (score 6):

You forgot a parameter:

```
-m, --create-home             create the dummy's home directory
```

Are you sure you set the correct owner and permission to the directory?

```
$ ls -ld /home dummy
drwx------ dummy dummy ........... dummy

$ chown dummy:dummy /home/dummy
$ chmod 700 /home/dummy
```

If you've already files in the directory, add an extra `-R` to both commands.

Comment: `-m` is present in the command, look closely.

Comment: I stand corrected.

Comment: `-m` is shown in the question, but then OP still had to run `mkdir`?  I think some information is missing.  Maybe there was an error.  Or maybe OP ran `useradd` without `-m` the first time.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid such mistakes, you should use the perl script `adduser` that comes with ubuntu. It's a wrapper around `useradd` that helps you to perform the operation in a wizard style [->[source]](http://www.go2linux.org/useradd-vs-adduser)...

Answer (score -1):

In `/etc/login.defs`, change the system wide setting `CREATE_HOME` and set it to `yes`.